# Receive array from and set as value in another function

Tags: javascript

So what I believe I need to do  is take the array that I built in the decorateResponse function. Then call it in the addVideosToStore function. Then inside that function, pass that value into the store.videos array. Im just  not sure on how to go about that.

```
const store = {
 videos: []
};

const decorateResponse = function(response) {
  const responseData = response.items.map(function(item) {
    return {
    id: item.id,
    title: item.title,
    thumbnail: item.thumbnails.default
   };
 });
return responseData;
};
```

// TASK:
// 1. Create a `addVideosToStore` function that receives an array of decorated video 
// objects and sets the array as the value held in store.videos
// TEST IT!

```
const addVideosToStore = function(videos) {

};
```

Comment: If there isn't missing something really essential, then that's a simple assignment.

Comment: @Andreas would it be as simple as store.videos.push(decorateResponse);

Comment: @user10129294 store.videos = decorateResponse(resp)